# AsynTask Android Development: Trouble in passing parameter in AsyncTask

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am newbie to android. Building an app which needs some tasks to be done in background.Following is a snippet of the code.

```
public class YQL extends AsyncTask <List,Void,List>
{   @Override
    protected List doInBackground(List... Suggestions) {
                //doing some stuff using Suggestions[0]
    }    
}
```

I have an object of List class which is,mySuggestions, which i need to pass into async task. But as async task takes only arrays as input I tried the below thing.

```
YQL yqlMain = new YQL();
List[] temp = null;
temp[0] =  mySuggestions
yqlMain.execute(temp);
```

Didn't work. 
Error :Null pointer access: The variable temp can only be null.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Abhi is this really the code? I doubt you understand about background processes but yet miss that Arrays in java are fix sized thus if you declare it null you can't reference anything in it, specially next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp` is null, but you are calling an operation in it. That gives the `NullPointerException`.

The following code should do the trick (untested)

```
public class YQL extends AsyncTask <String,Void,List>
{   
    @Override
    protected List doInBackground(String... Suggestions) {

    }    
}
```

Execution:

```
YQL ygl = new YQL();
ygl.Execute("Suggestion 1", "Suggestion 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong .. do something like

```
List temp = new ArrayList();
temp.add(mySuggestions);
yqlMain.execute(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Then

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
..
..
}
```

Check this link:
[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)